# C# dispose of filestream on an api controller

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, filestream

I am receiving the warning

> warning CA2000: Call System.IDisposable.Dispose on object created by
> 'new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open)' before all references to it are
> out of scope.

for the api controller

```
  [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult DownloadFile(long id)
        {
            var uploadPath = Path.Combine(fileServer, Constants.UploadFolder);
            Models.File file = repository.GetById(id);

            var path = Path.Combine(uploadPath, $"{file.FileGuid.ToString()}{file.FileExtension}");
            var fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open);
            return File(fs, "application/octet-stream", file.FileName);
        }
```

unfortunately switching to using to remove the warning message

```
using (var fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open)) 
  return File(fs, "application/octet-stream", file.FileName);
```

results in an error when running the api

> An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
> ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a disposed object. Object name:
> 'Cannot access a closed file.'. System.IO.FileStream.BeginRead(byte[]
> array, int offset, int numBytes, AsyncCallback callback, object state)

Comment: You can ignore the error as `FileStreamResult` will dispose of the passed in stream.

Comment: yes I could suppress the warning (everything works fine without the using) but I would prefer not to suppress the warning if possible

Comment: Unfortunately, the warnings around Dispose are some of the most problematic in terms of their false positives. Often suppressing them at specific sites *is* the best approach